# Reading CSV file in D3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to read a simple CSV file which is `"employee.csv"`:

```
Name, Age
Janik, 24
Jakob, 45
Anna, 30
Niklas, 35
```

The D3 script that I have to attempt this `"employee.csv"` file is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
        <title>Loading CSV file in D3</title>
        <script src = "./d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            d3.csv("./employee.csv", function(data)
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        console.log(data[i]);
                        //console.log(data[i].Name);
                        //console.log(data[i].Age);
                    }

                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This outputs each line from the CSV file. However, if I try to access each of the values from `Age` column, using the line

```
console.log(data[i].Age);
```

It gives the output `undefined` for each of the rows, whereas the the names are read fine

```
console.log(data[i].Name)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using d3 v5, the d3.csv method is changed:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the spaces in your csv file. Format it like this:

```
Name,Age
Janik,24
Jakob,45
Anna,30
Niklas,35
```

Here's a working Plunker that demonstrates the fix for your problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XVo37T9WcKiLPIpIQHyv?p=preview

[image: No spaces before commas in csv files.]
[image: Now it works.]