# How to load data from a CSV file in D3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to load data from a CSV file in D3; I have this code:

```
function update (error, data) {
    if (error !== null) {
        alert ("Couldn't load the dataset!");
    } else {
        //do something
    };

function changeData () {
    d3.csv ("data/dataset.csv", update);
}
```

If I use D3 v4 it works fine, but if I switch to v5 it doesn't work anymore.
Can someone explain to me how to modify the code to make it work with D3 v5?

Comment: [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281531/unable-to-load-csv-to-d3/49281661#49281661) may point you in the right direction. The API around it channged slightly and now it returns a promise.

Comment: Take a look at the [changes markdown](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

Comment: @pmkro I can't close this as a duplicate because this question obviously is not a duplicate of that one you linked. On top of that, your answer for that one is wrong (regarding OP's question), you can even see a downvote. So, feel free to copy that answer here (without the stack snippets, stack snippet is for **running** code only) and deleting that one, since it's wrong.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, repostedy answer on the more appropriate question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[d3 v5](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) uses the fetch API and returns a promise requiring the below code.

```
d3.csv('yourcsv.csv')
  .then(function(data) {
      // data is now whole data set
      // draw chart in here!
  })
  .catch(function(error){
     // handle error   
  })
```

In case in the future people want v4. [d3 v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) on the other hand uses the XMLHttpRequest method, and does not return a promise requiring this code

```
d3.csv('yourcsv.csv', function(data) {
    //whole data set
    // draw chart here
})
```

csv loading is async so make sure to run your chart code within the csv function.

Comment: Removed the depends on version. Kept the version 4 code for people who find this later.

Comment: @Bananasaurus If the response is *not ok*, i.e. HTTP status other than 200-299, the returned promise will be rejected. You can use [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) to handle these errors. D3 will not report any other errors nor will it give you access to the `Response` object. This has been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/issues/7) but was rejected by Mike Bostock, who encourages the use of the Fetch API should there be any need for further error handling.

Comment: I'm getting a `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined`

Comment: @Zee which browser are you using? This should work for all modern browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Browser_compatibility You may need a polyfill to support IE versions.

Answer (score 8):

[@pmkro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49604124) is good, but if you want to use ES7 [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead of Promise.then:

```
async function doThings() {
  const data = await d3.csv('yourcsv.csv');
  // do whatever with data here
}

doThings();
```

Comment: Can I sync with it? There are a complete example?  do 1 them do 2? `doThings1(); doThings2();`.