# Loading CSV into d3 v5, v6

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am following the examples for reading CSV with Promises described in [How to load data from a CSV file in D3 v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599691/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-in-d3-v5)

but neither suggested solutions are working for me.

```
d3.csv('./data_files/NYC.csv')
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
     console.log('oops ' + error);
  })
```

produces Error 0.  I know it is not an URL problem because when I specify a non-existent file it returns file not found error.

The other solution suggested is

```
async function doThings() {
  const data = await d3.csv('./data_files/NYC.csv');
  console.log(data)
}

doThings();
```

which produces "Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: 0

This seems straightforward but I can't figure it out.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems to have been a CORS problem.  Either though I have disabled Cross-Origin Restrictions in the developer tools in Safari, CORS seems to be the problem.  When I ran it on a server, the above code worked fine.